# SQL Query Takes 15 to 20 sec

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, refactoring, sql-tuning

[image: The Query Explain Plan Link]

The below Query is taking 15 to 20 Sec which is not expected. Please help in refactoring this query

```
SELECT upin.bipuserid userid,
       upin.orgn_entity_id entityId,
       COUNT(upin.ORGN_ENTITY_ID)
           over (partition BY upin.bipuserid) as numentities,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(SUBSTR(upin.ORGN_ENTITY_ID,6,2)))
           over (partition BY upin.bipuserid) as numentitytypes
FROM userpermission upin;
```

There are 1614246 Records in the table. Index has been created on both columns.

Below is the table structure

```
Column Name        Data Type    

BIPUSERID         VARCHAR2 (20 Char)            
ROLECODE          VARCHAR2 (25 Char)            
ORGN_ENTITY_ID    VARCHAR2 (10 Char)            
ACT_CD            VARCHAR2 (1 Char)
```

Comment: Could you post performance of the query without `numentitytypes` column?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51284558/edit) to include [the execution plan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.html) for the query (as text, not an image).

Comment: Explain Plan Pic Link has been added in the Description

Answer (score 1):

How long does this query take?

```
select count(orgn_entity_id) as numentities ,
       count(distinct substr(upin.ORGN_ENTITY_ID, 6, 2) ) as numentitytypes
from userpermission upin
group by upin.bipuserid;
```

If this is significantly faster, then you can `join` these results back in.  This may be able to take advantage of an index on `userpermission(bipuserid, substr(upin.ORGN_ENTITY_ID, 6, 2), orgn_entity_id)`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, This is significantly Faster But does not give me the required result for numentities and numentitytypes

Comment: @GaganDeep . . . If this doesn't give the right values, then the window functions won't either.  This should have the right values, but just one per `bipuserid` row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what @GordonLinoff was suggesting was that you should use his query as a basis for something like the following:

```
WITH cteCounts AS (SELECT BIPUSERID,
                          COUNT(ORGN_ENTITY_ID) AS NUMENTITIES ,
                          COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTR(ORGN_ENTITY_ID, 6, 2) ) AS NUMENTITYTYPES
                     FROM USERPERMISSION
                     GROUP BY BIPUSERID)
SELECT c.BIPUSERID,
       up.ORGN_ENTITY_ID AS ENTITYID,
       c.NUMENTITIES,
       c.NUMENTITYTYPES
  FROM cteCounts c
  INNER JOIN USERPERMISSION up
    ON up.BIPUSERID = c.BIPUSERID
```

and add an index as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX USERPERMISSION_XXX(BIPUSERID, SUBSTR(ORGN_ENTITY_ID, 6, 2), ORGN_ENTITY_ID);
```

Create the index, then run the above query, and hopefully it'll work a bit quicker for you.

Best of luck.